# Action bar icon working fine on one activity not on other

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I am using following menu.xml for action bar menu and its working fine on my main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:title="navigation"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

But when I use same menu.xml on other activity menu icon doesn't appear. Here is a snapshot of my main activity 
    [image: both icons are visible in main activity]

Now here is a snapshot of my other activity.
    [image: here icons are not visible]
Why am I facing this problem, Please let me know your feedback on it.

Here is my onCreateOptionsMenu code

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test,menu);
        return true;
    }
```

I am using this code for both activity.

Here is the code of my SecondActivity

```
package com.example.actionbar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

    }
     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "navigation selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                 .show();
            }
            if(id == R.id.action_settings){
                 Toast.makeText(this, "settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                 .show();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your onCreateOptionsMenu for both activities pls.

Comment: Post `onOptionsItemSelected` method. If you haven't overridden this method then you should.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with it, can you post the entire code for your second activity ?

Comment: yes i have posted whole code of second activity, on first activity it works find but on second activity i am still facing the same issue

Comment: I notice that at one place you're using R.menu.action_menu and at another place you're using R.menu.test. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

have you used onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected method in the other activity if no then try it...

Comment: menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(true);
menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(true)
try this in other activity of your onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: @pushpendra 
menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(true); menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(true);
try this in the other activity's onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: setHasOptionsMenu(true);
use it in oncreate method of that activity. and have you used the above code below
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu,menu);
??

Comment: i have seen your edited code 
correct your R.menu.----
in the place of dashes you have to use the name of the main xml where you are using your two items refresh and settings.
it must be same on both activities oncreateoptionmenu method and where evere you want to use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61889/discussion-between-pushpendra-and-hulk-saviour).

Comment: i don't have that repo unfortunately